# Center Child QMainWindow Relative to Parent QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

The area of focus is on this part of the code:

```
prect = self.parent.rect() # <===
prect1 = self.parent.geometry() # <===
center = prect1.center() # <===
self.move(center) # <===
```

When I use `prect.center()`, it centers the box correctly in the center, but if I move the window and use the menu (Action > Show Window2), `Window2` doesn't show centered relative to the parent window.

When I use `prect1.center()`, it doesn't center the box correctly (top-left coordinate of `Window2` is in the center) but it does move relative to the parent window if I move the parent window somewhere else.

**Question**: How do I alter my code to show `Window2` in the center of `Window` relative to wherever `Window` is at on the screen?

**Reproducible code example:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        menu = self.menuBar()
        action = menu.addMenu("&Action")
        show_window2 = QAction("Show Window2", self)
        action.addAction(show_window2)
        show_window2.triggered.connect(self.show_window2_centered)

        self.show()

    def show_window2_centered(self):                                             
        self.w = Window2(parent=self)
        self.w.show()

class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Centered Window")

        prect = self.parent.rect() # <===
        prect1 = self.parent.geometry() # <===
        center = prect1.center() # <===
        self.move(center) # <===
        print(prect)
        print(prect1)
        print(center)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Currently looks like this:

[image: Child QMainWindow not centered]

Would like it to be centered relative to the main window:

[image: centered QMainWindow to Parent]

Comment: Do you just want to focus at the beginning or do you want to be centered at all times?

Comment: Focused at the beginning. I just want it to be centered when I click the "Show Window2" command in the menu - relative to the main window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `self.w` is not a child of`Window` because you do not pass that parameter to `super()`. On the other hand `move()` does not center the widget in that position, what it does is that the top-left is located in that position.

The solution is to modify the geometry using the geometry of the other element since they are both windows:

```py
class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Centered Window")

        geo = self.geometry()
        geo.moveCenter(self.parent.geometry().center())
        self.setGeometry(geo)
```

Comment: Nice! I'll probably spend the next few hours studying these three lines. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jarad You have to differentiate geometry and rect, geometry refers to the rectangle with respect to the parent if it has it and if it does not have it, it will be respect to the screen, and rect refers to itself. If you want a rectangle to be centered with respect to another one, it is necessary that the center be the same